# IMAP - JavaMail - How to know which messages to process?

Tags: jakarta-mail, imap

**What I want to achieve:**

- I am coding a Java program that uses IMAP to connect to some gmail accounts every 5 minutes and extract information from some messages.
- I want to check all the messages (incoming and outgoing) and take only the ones I have not processed. By "processed" I do not mean only "read" or "seen" messages. My application does not care whether or not another user has accessed that account and read a message. My application needs to keep track of which was the last message it processed and, the next time it goes through the messages, start with the first non-processed message.
- I do not want to change anything in the messages. I do not want to mark them as seen or read.

**What I have implemented:**

- Establish IMAP connection.
- Open and access all messages in "[Gmail]/All Mail" folder.

**What I have tried:**

- I have been reading about UID and message number, but I am not sure if any of them could help me achieve what I want. Maybe UID could, but: how do I retrieve it with JavaMail?
- I found Folder.getMessages(int start, int end), but I think it refers to the index of the message in a folder, which I believe can easily change.

Can anyone provide some guidance at what is the best approach to take here?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use UIDs: any incoming message will have a UID higher than previous message.  Just remember the highest UID you have processed, and process ones with higher UIDs.

Comment: Thanks, @Max. Does this also apply for sent messages? How can I get the UID using JavaMail? UIDs do not change even if moved to another folder, right?

Comment: Hey @Max. It's me again, I found Interface UIDFolder with its two implementations: GmailFolder and IMAPFolder. I will read a bit more to know which one would be the right one for me. If you have any suggestions, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: UIDs are +not+ maintained if they are copied to another folder. Each folder has independent UIDs. If you are using gmail, you can get the internal gmail id, but that is a non-standard extension. I do not know javamail, just protocol specifics.

Comment: Thanks, @Max. As you can see in the comments of the answer, arnt says gmail handles UIDs correctly in the "All Mail" folder. I am implementing this assuming UIDs in "All Mail" folder do not change. I will make some test and post the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMAP UIDs are relative to the folder containing the message.  I don't know how Gmail handles UIDs for messages in the "[Gmail]/All Mail" folder, but if it does the right thing you could use the [UIDFolder](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/UIDFolder.html) interface to get the UIDs.  And as described, once you've processed a certain UID, all the new messages will have larger UIDs, which can make processing more efficient.

The alternative is to use Message-IDs, which has a different set of problems...

Comment: Gmail does the right thing; using UIDs and the allmail folder is a good solution for this question.

Comment: Thanks, @arnt. I am currently implementing this solution and I will make some tests, moving messages around to see if the UIDs are working as expected. Do you have a link to some documentation where it is explained how gmail handles UIDs in the "[Gmail]/All Mail" folder?

Comment: No. RFC 3501 specifies how UIDs are to be handled, I just happen to know that gmail follows the spec, even in the case of that folder. (One might expect that folder to be special, and it is. Many clients issue commands such as UID FETCH 1:* FLAGS. Do that on a large gmail/allmail, and you'll feel a Special feeling. Many clients expect SELECT to complete in a second or two, which is not the case on a large allmail folder. But it follows the spec.)

Comment: I have been testing and everything is working as expected using UIDs and the "all mail" folder. Thanks!